Binding DrawingImage to custom UserControl in ItemsControl
First time asking here, feeling desperate.
I want to bind DrawingImage (as is) to corresponding property of custom UserControl, that is created by ItemsControl. This is not an WPF Application, but rather class library (addin for other software), so some features are not available.
My main idea is to build UI dynamically at start (grouped buttons, each button starts it's own command in separate dll). Button is custom usercontrol named ToolButtonControl. The structure of buttons in different groups derived from some local folder structure. Different folders contains all separate tools dll-s.
Instead of MainWindow there is Page, that contains ItemsControl. There is nothing else in this page, so I omit everything else:
xaml:
<Grid Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
      Focusable="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PluginsCollection"
          Source="{Binding Path=PluginsData, Mode=OneWay}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PanelName" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScrollView" 
                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle_custom}" 
                  Focusable="true"
                  Margin=" 0,5,0,5">

        <ItemsControl Margin="10" Name="myItemsControl"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PluginsCollection}}">

                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <GroupBox Header="{Binding Name}">
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </GroupBox>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UIBuilderViewModel}">

                    <uc:ToolButtonControl   Title="{Binding PluginTitle}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Margin="5"
                                            Icon="{Binding IconImage}"
                                            AssemblyPath="{Binding Path}"
                                            ToolButtonClick="RunCommand"/>

                </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

codebehind:
public partial class ToolbarMainPage : Page
{
    public ToolbarMainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new UIBuilderViewModel();
    }
}

UIBuilderViewModel class:
public class UIBuilderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<PluginItem> PluginsData {  get; set; } 

    public UIBuilderViewModel()
    {
        var loadedData = LoadPluginsUtils.LoadOnlyPlugins();

        PluginsData = new ObservableCollection<PluginItem>(loadedData);
    }
}


PluginItem model:
public class PluginItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PluginTitle { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string PanelName { get; set; }
    public DrawingImage IconImage { get; set; }
    public Assembly Assembly { get; set; }
}

List of PluginItem's is collected on startup like so:
public static List<PluginItem> LoadOnlyPlugins()
{
    // the code for reading folder structure is ommited since it works completely fine

    var items = new List<PluginItem>();

    foreach (var file in somedir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(file.FullName) == ".dll")
        {
            foreach (Type loadableType in GetLoadableTypes(Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName)))
            {
                if (loadableType.GetInterface("IToolsPlugin") != (Type)null)
                {
                    if (!(Activator.CreateInstance(loadableType) is IToolsPlugin instance))
                        continue;

                    plugin.IconImage = instance.IconImage; // Here IconImage is NOT null

                    break;
                }
            }

            plugin.PluginTitle = toolName;
            plugin.FileName = file.Name;
            plugin.PanelName = panelName;
            plugin.Path = file.FullName;
            plugin.Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
        }
    }

    items.Add(plugin);

    return items;
}

Every separate tool have reference to main project, and implements IToolsPlugin interface.
This is my (maybe clumsy) way to read DrawingImage icon from xaml file that is stored inside each tool dll. Interface implemented like so:
public class ToolsConnector : IToolsPlugin
{
    private static ToolsConnector _instance;

    //Below is the test code that makes using xaml icon in ToolKit Page possible

    ResourceDictionary _rd = new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("/dtt_sockets;component/icon.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    };

    public DrawingImage IconImage => _rd["icon_sockets"] as DrawingImage;
}

I need implement all this because:

I need icons to be in vector and to have DynamicResource in Pen.Brush
I need icons to be in each dll itself, and not in separate file (in case you would suggest to use *.svg)

And, finally, my cusom ToolButtonControl goes like this:
codebehind:
public partial class ToolButtonControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickToolbuttonEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "ToolButtonClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ToolButtonControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ToolButtonClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(ClickToolbuttonEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ClickToolbuttonEvent, value); }
    }

    public ToolButtonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ClickToolbuttonEvent));


    public static DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Icon),
        typeof(DrawingImage),
        typeof(ToolButtonControl));

    public DrawingImage Icon
    {
        get { return (DrawingImage)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AssemblyPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AssemblyPath), typeof(string),
        typeof(ToolButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string AssemblyPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(AssemblyPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AssemblyPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Title), typeof(string),
        typeof(ToolButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
}

xaml (only main content, with no extra details):
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Margin="0,0,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Image  x:Name="toolIcon"
            Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Height="14"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                x:Name="tbTitle"
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource OpenSans regular}"
                FontSize="13"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="{DynamicResource MainFontBrush}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                Margin="13,-2,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Button x:Name="StartToolButton"
                FontSize="12"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="Transparent"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Click="button_click"/>
</Grid>

The icon itself:
<ResourceDictionary 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Tools;component/App.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DrawingImage x:Key="icon_sockets">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M24,24z M0,0z M9.5,11L9.5,12.5">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="{DynamicResource MainFontBrush}" Thickness="1.5" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M24,24z M0,0z M14.5,11L14.5,12.5">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="{DynamicResource MainFontBrush}" Thickness="1.5" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F0 M24,24z M0,0z M18,21.0139L6,21.0139C4.343,21.0139,3,19.6709,3,18.0139L3,6.01392C3,4.35692,4.343,3.01392,6,3.01392L18,3.01392C19.657,3.01392,21,4.35692,21,6.01392L21,18.0139C21,19.6709,19.657,21.0139,18,21.0139z">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="{DynamicResource MainFontBrush}" Thickness="1.5" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F0 M24,24z M0,0z M12,18.5C15.5899,18.5 18.5,15.5899 18.5,12 18.5,8.41015 15.5899,5.5 12,5.5 8.41015,5.5 5.5,8.41015 5.5,12 5.5,15.5899 8.41015,18.5 12,18.5z">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="{DynamicResource MainFontBrush}" Thickness="1.5" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" MiterLimit="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</ResourceDictionary>

So the problem is that in main Page, in ItemsControl, all bindings of ToolButtonControl works as expected (Title, AssemblyPath, etc), but DrawingImage won't bind. It's just not showing.
If I hardcode some DrawingImage to Image source (even from PluginsData ObservableCollection, where DrawingImages of each item is certainly not null) - it is showing.
I tried every single type of binding, with and without RelativeSource, in Page and in UserControl - still no image is rendered. I know for sure that the IconImage property is not null when each UserControl is initialized, but for some reason it won't bind. Although every single other property binds fine.
P.S. - in the first version I built UI with for loop in codeBehind of MainPage, and all was working as expected. But then decided to go for MVVM, and this happened.
Also: I need to set the UI once at startup, and since then it's immutable. So I don't implement PropertyChanged notifiers etc.
Please don't suggest using svg or png, unless what I am trying to achieve is impossible.
I've tried all types of DataBinding to UserControl in MainPage and to Image element in UserControl itself. I tried hardcoding DrawingImage to Image.Source and it works fine. It won't bind in ItemsControl.
I also tried to put plain Image in ItemsControl instead of custom UserControl, with same binding to source - still no image rendered. So the problem is not with UserControl.
All other properties working as expected, and DrawingImages in ObservableCollection is not null, so the collection is full and fine.

Where is the binding source? Can you show it too, please?

Or have you mistyped your DatTemplate? The DataTemplate.DataType is UIBuilderViewModel (which is not shown). But from context (binding source property names) it appears like the data type should be the PluginItem? Is that correct? And is it also correct that PluginItem does not implement INOtifyPropertyChanged? Would you mind not posting isolated code fragments?  It's really important to see all relevant details including your class signatures. Details really matter.

Why is there ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PluginsData}}" when the Page has a DataContext with a PluginsData property? Shouldn't that be ItemsSource="{Binding PluginsData}"?

@BionicCode UIBuilderViewModel seems to be called MainViewModel.

@BionicCode ItemsControl item's source is "PluginsData" ObservableCollection. It is set in UIBuilderViewModel class, and populated by LoadOnlyPlugins() method.

@Clemens Ahh, ok. To me  it looks like he just missed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Because he is populating the souurce collection after the InitializeComponent call. This would explain why the values are not send to the binding target.

Does PluginItem implement INotifyPropertyChaged?

@Boris Please use consistent naming. Don't call a class named UIBuilderViewModel MainViewModel.

@BionicCode I named this block "MainViewModel" by the force of habit, sorry. Edited the post

PluginsData should be a readonly property: public ObservableCollection<PluginItem> PluginsData { get; } = new();

I see. This happens. Maybe you should create the examples in your IDE to ensure that you don't post code that doesn't build ;)

@Clemens about {Binding Source={StaticResource PluginsData}} - in full code there is also a CollectionViewSource for grouping purposes, so ItemsSource is bound to that. I omitted that for example, but forgot to format ItemsSource of ItemsControl.

@Boris Make sure you show reproducible code, not just something thrown together.

about INotifyPropertyChaged implementation - I tried with and without it. In example I omitted it, since other bindings works as expected. I think the problem is in DrawingImage itself, because strings and even Assembly  binds just fine.

Then have you tried to register a ToolButtonControl.Icon dependency property changed callback to set a breakpoint into it to check if the value ever arrives? Maybe your DrawingImage is composed erroneously. It's also not shown or I overlooked it. If the call back is called and the new value is the DrawingImage then you must check your DrawingImage composition.

@BionicCode Does it counts as "working DrawingImage" if I can hardcode it into Image source in codebehind and it is indeed visualizing as expected?

Have you verified that the ResourceDictionaries are loaded correctly? Is /dtt_sockets;component/icon.xaml a valid URI in all "tool dlls"?

@BionicCode I can see it in my ObservableCollection Items while debugging, DrawingImage is there and is not null. And since I can render it different way - I guess the DrawingImage itself is fine.  Is it ever arrives - good question, I don't really know how to check it. I will look it up, thanks.

@Clemens about URI - for now (for test and POC) there is only one dll, so only one item in ObservableCollection. I am 100% sure that icon is read from ResourceDictionary by that URI. The URI is specified in that separate tool dll, and it will be different for every other dll. Main "app" is looking for specific interface in that dll's, and when such found - it takes DrawingImage specified by URI.  It all works fine without xaml binding (if bound in codebehind). But I just want to do things MVVM-ish way

As a note, the declaration public static UIBuilderViewModel ViewModel; is wrong. The field should not be static. Besides that, it should not be a field, but a property, and it is questionable if you need it at all. You could simple write DataContext = new UIBuilderViewModel();

@Clemens Not making an excuse - it was that way initially. At some point in my attempts I was trying to access VM from another place, maybe to hardcode something for tests. And left it that way for now. Anyway it not affecting the problem as I checked.

Edited the post: Added full code of MainPage with ListCollectionView, added icon.xaml, and made other edits according to project files.

So, when in debug mode then instance.IconImage inside LoadOnlyPlugins is definitely  not NULL? If that's the case I ask you to post a minimal example (that compiles and was tested to reproduce the issue). It appears like you are missing something to show to us. Based on your posted code it doesn't make sense to me. If the resource path is properly resolved and the PluginItem implements INotifyProeprtyCHanged AND raises the PropertyChanged event then you must have missed something.

It would be great if we could review your "complete" code without the snippets scattered all over and out of context. Just strip off everything that is not required and then build and run your new example. This would be great. Sorry for the extra effort, but I hope my request makes sense to you. It hopefully  makes the endless interviews in this comment section redundant.

@BionicCode definately not null. INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in Model and in ViewModel, but PropertyChanged event never fired. I tried to put plain Image control in my Page, without ItemsControl etc, and bind Source to new property in VM (which definately has DrawingImage in it) - it just won't work, only if I hardcode it in codebehind. It feels like xaml is initialized before all VM's properties are filled with data, DrawingImages in particular.

About fully compileable code - as I wrote in post - it is a class library made to run as Addin for other software. Without this software you can't reproduce it, I afraid. And (I know it may sound weird) I can't even tell what software it is, because my organization won't let me. So I guess I am on my own here. Sorry if I took your time to no avail.

Ok, I've found a workaround to my problem.
It turns out that Page is initialized at hosting application's startup (an instance of ToolbarMainPage is created when dockable pane is registered), but it's not visualized yet. When some document in hosting app is opened - then dockable pane is rendered, and only then UserControl instances is created by ItemsControl (ToolButtonControl instances).
So the problem was in that timing difference - somehow DrawingImage prop in ItemsControl's  UserControls could not be binded until UC is rendered. Text props works fine, but DrawingImage (and probably Image) has some quirk to it.
My workaround is breaking MVVM by introducing code-behind, but at this point - whatever.
I am taking advantage of UC's Loaded event:
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mv:PluginItem}">
        <uc:ToolButtonControl   Title="{Binding PluginTitle}"
                                Icon="{Binding Icon}"
                                XamlUri="{Binding URI}" <-- this is not working properly eiter.
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="5"
                                AssemblyPath="{Binding Path}"
                                ToolButtonClick="RunCommand"
                                Loaded="ToolIconUpdater"/>  <--- this

    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

And in code-behind:
private void ToolIconUpdater(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = e.OriginalSource as ToolButtonControl;

    ResourceDictionary _rd = new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri(t.XamlUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
    };

    t.Icon = (DrawingImage)_rd["ic_icon"];
}

I am also changed DrawingImage type of Icon property to just Uri to icon xaml.
In my XamlUri property I have PropertyMetadata set with default Uri to default icon to start things up, and then ItemsControl items is initialized, and Loaded event fired to change icons.
